# Remote Runspace connection against Exchange fails

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, runspace, winrm

I want to issue commands to an Exchange server remotely through C#. When I do this directly through PowerShell, it works. But when I issue commands to PowerShell via C#, it fails.

Here is what I'm doing in PowerShell (which works):

```
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://ExchangeFQDN/PowerShell/ -Authentication Kerberos
Import-PSSession $Session
Enable-Mailbox -Identity "SomeIdentity" -Shared
```

Here is the C# (doesn't work):

```
var connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(
    new Uri("http://ExchangeFQDN/PowerShell/"),
    "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange", 
    new PSCredential(username, password));
connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Kerberos;

//Next line throws a PSInvalidOperationException
using (var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo)) //<- fails
{
    //Execute Enable-Mailbox command 
}
```

I have a particular user that has the rights to do this remote login. The PowerShell is run as this user, while the user is impersonated in the C# code. It's also this user's username and password I pass in as the PSCredential.

Any thoughts on what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try following two possible solutions:

1. check the user name, domain name and password of the credential
2. replace new PSCredential(username, password) with PSCredential.Empty, which will use credential of current user, then run the program as the same user you used for powershell

Maybe you could provide more infomation about the error message.